# How Do I Reset My Running Counter in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I have a Reset button, so to speak (it's actually a drop-down menu item). When you click on it, in theory it should clear everything (the listbox, textboxes, labels, etc...) and reset the running total to 0.

It does not. I can reset the label TEXT to 0 using any of these 3: 
lbl1.text = "0" or "" or String.isEmpty

But the running counter maintains the last entry in memory and so when I try to start a new counter it just tacks on the new value to the existing one. Which is not what I want.

For instance let's say I before I reset the parent form, my counter was at 25 and I have a constant of 5. I reset my form, everything appears to go to zero. But when I start counting again, my counter tells me that my value is now 30 instead of 5. And it should be 5 if I'm starting from the beginning again.

I'm working with Modules and Forms here, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
 Private Sub ResetToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResetToolStripMenuItem.Click
    boxProducts.Items.Clear()
    lblSubtotal.Text = "0"
    lblTax.Text = "0"
    lblShipping.Text = "0"
    lblTotal.Text = "0"
End Sub
```

Here's my Module:

```
Module Module1
Const decTax As Decimal = 0.06
Dim decShipping As Decimal = 2.0
Dim decTotalTax As Decimal
Dim decTotalPrice As Decimal
Dim decTotalShipping As Decimal
Dim decSubtotal As Decimal
Dim decPrintPrice As Decimal
Dim decAudioPrice As Decimal
Function getPrintPrice(ByVal strPrintName As String) As Decimal
    If strPrintName = "I Did It Your Way (Print)" Then
        decPrintPrice = 11.95
    ElseIf strPrintName = "The History of Scotland (Print)" Then
        decPrintPrice = 14.5
    ElseIf strPrintName = "Learn Calculus in One Day (Print)" Then
        decPrintPrice = 29.95
    ElseIf strPrintName = "Feel the Stress" Then
        decPrintPrice = 18.5
    End If
    Return decPrintPrice
End Function

Function getAudioPrice(ByVal strAudioName As String) As Decimal
    If strAudioName = "Learn Calculus in One Day (Audio)" Then
        decAudioPrice = 29.95
    ElseIf strAudioName = "The History of Scotland (Audio)" Then
        decAudioPrice = 14.5
    ElseIf strAudioName = "Learn Calculus in One Day (Audio)" Then
        decAudioPrice = 29.95
    ElseIf strAudioName = "Feel the Stress (Audio)" Then
        decAudioPrice = 18.5
    End If
    Return decAudioPrice
End Function

Function getSubtotal(ByVal strName As String) As Decimal
    If strName = "I Did It Your Way (Print)" Then
        decSubtotal += 11.95
    ElseIf strName = "The History of Scotland (Print)" Then
        decSubtotal += 14.5
    ElseIf strName = "The History of Scotland (Audio)" Then
        decSubtotal += 14.5
    ElseIf strName = "Learn Calculus in One Day (Print)" Then
        decSubtotal += 29.95
    ElseIf strName = "Learn Calculus in One Day (Audio)" Then
        decSubtotal += 29.95
    ElseIf strName = "Feel the Stress (Print)" Then
        decSubtotal += 18.5
    ElseIf strName = "Relaxation Techniques (Audio)" Then
        decSubtotal += 11.5
    End If
    Return decSubtotal
End Function

Function getTotalShipping(ByVal strName As String) As Decimal
    decTotalShipping += decShipping
    Return decTotalShipping
End Function
Function getTax(ByVal strName As String) As Decimal
    decTotalTax = decTax * decSubtotal
    Return decTotalTax
End Function End Module
```

Comment: What is your counter exactly ?

Comment: I think it's more of a running total. I'm designing a shopping cart app, and every time I add a book the app retrieves the price and adds it to the current subtotal. When I hit the reset tab the total should go back to 0.

Comment: Do you store the running total in a variable? Can you show some more code?

Comment: Yeah sure, hold on.

Comment: `Dim decShipping As Decimal = 2.0`?

Comment: That's my shipping rate. It's a flat fee of $2.

Comment: You don't reset anything but the labels. You need to reset your variables as well.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct YES! How do I do that?

Comment: @Polly I should have explained:  You have your question tagged wrong.  VBA refers to Visual Basic for Automation. Where as your code is VB.Net.

Comment: If the problem is that it's in another module, something like `Module1.yourvariable = 0`?

Comment: @ThomasInzina OH. Okay. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Can I do it that way?

Comment: Don't put solved in the title.  Checking the answer is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub ResetToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResetToolStripMenuItem.Click
    boxProducts.Items.Clear()
    lblSubtotal.Text = "0"
    lblTax.Text = "0"
    lblShipping.Text = "0"
    lblTotal.Text = "0"

    decShipping = 0
    decTotalTax = 0
    decTotalPrice = 0
    decTotalShipping = 0
    decSubtotal = 0
    decPrintPrice = 0
    decAudioPrice = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm... doesn't work. Probably because my variables are all declared in my Module. Darn.

Comment: Oh wait. Nevermind. I got it. Your answer helped A LOT. THANK YOU @ThomasInzina